# Recording Audio Video IM

Tags: video-recording, lync-2013, skype-for-business, skypedeveloper

I am researching Skype For Business Web SDK to enable IM/Video/Audio/Meetings on my website (.Net application).

I am not able to find out,  how can I record conversations in my own Database or folder on the server?

As per my research, when user record conversations on Skype for Business client, data get saved client side.

My requirement is that I want to keep all the history of audio/video conversations.

If any another tool in the market I can use please guide.

thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Verba](http://www.verba.com/skype-for-business-recording-and-compliance). Verba is used widely in banking and finance sector. I don't think you can use Verba in the client side though. You would need to set it up on the server side.